# How to access a different schema in a virtual method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to write a virtual (get) method for my MongoDb collection (`Parts`) which needs to access a different schema: I want it to assert if a document is 'obsolete' according to a timestamp available in a different (`Globals`) collection:

```
const partsSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
  },
  ...
}, {
  toObject: { virtuals: true },
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
});

partsSchema.virtual('obsolete').get(async function() {
  const timestamp = await Globals.findOne({ key: 'obsolescenceTimestamp' }).exec();
  return this.updatedAt < timestamp.value;
});
```

But when I do a find, I always get a `{}` in the `obsolete` field, and not a boolean value...

```
const p = await parts.find();

...
"obsolete": {},
...
```

Is there some way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I did try... No syntax error, but in `obsolete` I always get `{}`, and not a boolean... :-( Edited my question...

Comment: Virtuals only make sense for synchronous code. I would instead create a schema method @MarcoS

Comment: I need some sample code... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but there are a few obstacles you need to hurdle. As @Mohammad Yaser Ahmadi points out, these getters are best suited for synchronous operations, but you can use them in the way you're using them in your example.

So let's consider what's happening here:

```
partsSchema.virtual('obsolete').get(async function() {
  const timestamp = await Globals.findOne({ key: 'obsolescenceTimestamp' }).exec();
  return this.updatedAt < timestamp.value;
});
```

Since the `obsolete` getter is an `async` function, you will always get a Promise in the `obsolete` field when you query your parts collection. In other words, when you do this:

```
const p = await parts.find();
```

You will get this:

```
...
"obsolete": Promise { <pending> },
...
```

So besides getting the query results for `parts.find()`, you also need to resolve the `obsolete` field to get that `true` or `false` result.

Here is how I would write your code:

```
partsSchema.virtual('obsolete').get(async function() {
    const Globals = mongoose.model('name_of_globals_schema');
    const timestamp = await Globals.findOne({ key: 'obsolescenceTimestamp' });
    return this.updatedAt < timestamp.value;
});
```

Then when querying it...

```
    parts.findOne({_id: '5f76aee6d1922877dd769da9'})
        .then(async part => {
            const obsolete = await part.obsolete;
            console.log("If obsolete:", obsolete);
        })
```

Comment: Thanks. But I do not like my approach, it is the first and only came to my mind... I will do a findMany, and I'd better avoid to await for any item in results (which will be huge... :-)
if you have any better approach, please give some suggestion...